# After wp_insert_post() custom post type does not show in the admin

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-insert-post

I have an import script that uses wp_insert_post() to add events wordpress. The script works and is basically a foreach loop of array elements that calls the above function multiple times.

My issue is that in the admin for the event custom post type I see this:
[image: wordpress admin]

So I see a count having a value, but no posts found. If I filter dates nothing shows. Does anyone have any ideas?
NB: I can go to the url and it works for a single event. But not for multiple events.

Comment: You're going to need to share the relevant code if you expect any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the import script had post_status as 'published' not 'publish' hope this helps someone. :facepalm